# Spring mvc with hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am beginner in spring mvc, I want to create simple example but I am getting exception im my service layer here is the exception

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/haybet] threw exception      `enter code here`[Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.proffart.bet.controller.BetController.registerUser(BetController.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:177)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am getting exception when clicking on register button in register.jsp, I guess that the problem is with hibernate and mysql connection, please help me to find the problem.

Here are my files

Controller

```
package org.proffart.bet.controller;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.validation.Valid;


import org.proffart.bet.domain.User;
import org.proffart.bet.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class BetController {
UserService service;
//private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(BetController.class);

@RequestMapping(value="register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showRegisterForm(ModelMap model){
    User user = new User();
    model.addAttribute("user",user );
    return "register";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registerUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult result,
        ModelMap model){
    System.out.println(user.getNickName());
    System.out.println(user.getNickName());
    System.out.println(user);
    user.setBalance((double) 1);
    user.setEmail("aaa");
    user.setId(1);

    if (result.hasErrors()){
        return "register"; 
    }

    service.saveUser(user);
    return "success";

   }
}
```

DAO classes

```
package org.proffart.bet.dao;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class AbstractDAO {
     @Autowired
     private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

     protected Session getSession(){
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
     }

     public void persist(Object entity) {
         getSession().persist(entity);
     }
}
```

UserDao class

```
package org.proffart.bet.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.proffart.bet.domain.User;

public interface UserDAO {
    public void addUser(User user);
    public void deleteUser(Integer id);
    public List<User> getUsers();
}
```

UserDAOImpl

```
package org.proffart.bet.dao;

import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.proffart.bet.domain.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository 
public class UserDAOImpl extends AbstractDAO implements UserDAO{

   @Autowired
   private SessionFactory sessionFactory;   
   public void addUser(User user) {
       persist(user);       
   }

  public void deleteUser(Integer id) {

  }

  public List<User> getUsers() {

  }

}
```

Service classes
UserService

```
package org.proffart.bet.service;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.proffart.bet.dao.UserDAO;
import org.proffart.bet.dao.UserDAOImpl;
import org.proffart.bet.domain.User;

@Transactional
public class UserService {
     UserDAO dao;

     public void saveUser(User user){
        dao.addUser(user);
    }
}
```

Doamin layer
User

```
package org.proffart.bet.domain;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

@Id
@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

@Column(name="nic_name")
private String nickName;

@Column(name="email")
private String email;

@Column(name="password")
private String password;

@Column(name="balance")
private Double balance;

public String getEmail(){
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email){
    this.email = email;
}

public String getNickName(){
    return nickName;
}

public void setNickName(String nickName){
    this.nickName = nickName;
}

public String getPassword(){
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password){
    this.password = password;
}

public Double getBalance(){
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(Double balance){
    this.balance = balance;
}

public Integer getId(){
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id){
    this.id = id;
 }
}
```

Reguister.jsp

```
<%@ page session="true" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Welcome To Virtual bettings</h3>
    <form:form method="POST"  modelAttribute="user">
         <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="nickName">Login: </label> </td>
                <td><form:input path="nickName" id="nickName"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="password">Password: </label> </td>
                <td><form:input path="password" id="password"/></td>
            </tr>                
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="register"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally config files in xml
web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <context-param>
 <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
 <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml /WEB-INF/hibernateDataAccessContext.xml</param-    value>
 </context-param>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

hibernateDataAccessContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>
<!-- Auto-detect DAOs -->
<context:component-scan base-package="org.proffart.bet.dao"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="WEB-INF/jdbc.properties"/>

<bean id="dataSource"
class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
destroy-method="close"
p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
p:url="${jdbc.url}"
p:username="${jdbc.username}"
p:password="${jdbc.password}"
p:maxActive="${dbcp.maxActive}"
p:maxIdle="${dbcp.maxIdle}"
p:maxWait="${dbcp.maxWait}"/>


<bean id="sessionFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
p:configurationClass="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration"
p:packagesToScan="org.proffart.bet.domain">
<property name="hibernateProperties">
<props>
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${hibernate.generate_statistics}</prop>
</props>
</property>
<property name="eventListeners">
<map>
<entry key="merge">
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.IdTransferringMergeEventListener"/>
</entry>
</map>
</property>

</bean>


<!-- Allow declarative transaction management using the @Transactional annotation -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txnManager"/>

<!-- Transaction manager for the Hibernate SessionFactory -->
<bean id="txnManager"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"/>

<!-- Apply persistence exception translation on @Repository classes -->
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

</beans>
```

And dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="org.proffart.bet.controller" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>

</bean>
```

jdbc.properties

```
hibernate.generate_statistics=true
hibernate.show_sql=true
jpa.showSql=true

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect

jpa.databasePlatform=org.springframework.samples.petclinic.toplink.EssentialsHSQLPlatformWithNativeSequence

jpa.database=HSQL

jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bet
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=
```

Comment: Put `@Autowired` on your `UserService` field in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your exception shows a NullPointerException on line 47 of BetController. However there is nothing at this line in the class you posted. My guess is that your UserService is not injected in your controller. Add the @Autowired annotation:

```
@Controller
public class BetController {
   @Autowired
   UserService service;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)} after mentioned changes

Answer (score 0):

Put `@Service` annotation on `UserService` class,and `@Autowired` on the below line in `BetController` class.

```
@Autowired
UserService service;
```

And i see you setted component scanning to controller package only,how ever you need to set it to below.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.proffart.bet.*"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}  after mentioned changes

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss autowire Userservice object in to controller layer
Please add @autowire top of Userservice object It will sovles your problem.

@Autowire
UserService service;

If its give any problem just google how to autowire service object,

Also you have done one mistake while creating service object you need to create Userservice as Interface and one concert implementation of Userservice like UserServiceImpl

Thanks,
Himanshu

Answer (score 0):

This is the best example for Spring mvc crud operation using JQuery Ajax. You may find maven as well in this.

Site: [Spring MVC With Hibernate CRUD](http://sindhitutorials.com/videos/spring-mvc-hibernate-maven/spring-mvc-configuration-hibernate)

Or You may visit YouTube Channel: [Spring MVC with Hibernate CRUD VIDEO](https://youtu.be/8Gq-fEsN80U)